# Looping over CFHTTP cookie and issues setting up cookie

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to loop over a cookie coming from cfhttp but it is not displaying correct results.

Below is my code

```
<cfhttp url="#address#" method="get" throwOnError="Yes" resolveurl="false">
  <cfset cookies = cfhttp.responseHeader['Set-Cookie'] />
  <cfloop collection="#cookies#" item="k">
    <cfset temp = REReplace(k, ";.*", "")>
    <cfset cookieName = listfirst(temp,'=')>
    <cfset cookievalue = listlast(temp,'=')>
    <cfhttpparam type="cookie" name="#cookieName#" value="#cookievalue#">
  </cfloop>
  <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
  <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
</cfhttp>
```

Second attempt:

From one call, I am getting cookies and I am putting them in a structure as follows:

```
<cfset cookies = cfhttp.responseHeader['Set-Cookie'] />
<cfset cookieStruct=StructNew()>
<cfloop collection="#cookies#" item="key">
  <cfset cookieKeyAndValue = REReplace(key, ";.*", "")>
  <cfset cookieKey = listfirst(cookieKeyAndValue,'=')>
  <cfset cookieValue = listlast(cookieKeyAndValue,'=')>
  <cfset StructInsert(cookieStruct,cookieKey,cookieValue)>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#cookieStruct#" abort>
<cfhttp url="#addr#" method="get" throwOnError="Yes" resolveurl="false" result="objAddress">
  <cfloop collection="#cookieStruct#" item="key">
    <cfhttpparam type="cookie" name="#key#" value="#cookieStruct[key]#">
  </cfloop>
  <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
  <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
</cfhttp>
```

This is giving me an error:

> Invalid collection ASPJGASGHSG=KBHFPN; path=/. Must be a valid structure or COM object. Loop error.

Comment: Your description is very vague. What actually happens? How is the result different than what you expected? What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: (Edit) The error message looks pretty clear. The returned value ie cfhttp.responseHeader['Set-Cookie'] is not a structure. You need to [parse the value and create your own structure](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/725-maintaining-sessions-across-multiple-coldfusion-cfhttp-requests.htm).

Answer (score 0):

CFHTTP GET returns a result into the CFHTTP data structure. Having the loop inside the CFHTTP open/close tag results in trying to loop over something that does not exist yet.

```
<cfhttp url="#address#" method="get" throwOnError="Yes" resolveurl="false" >
    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
</cfhttp>

<cfset cookies = cfhttp.responseHeader['Set-Cookie'] />
<cfloop collection="#cookies#" item="k">
    <cfset temp = REReplace(k, ";.*", "")>
    <cfset cookieName = listfirst(temp,'=')>
    <cfset cookievalue = listlast(temp,'=')>
</cfloop>
```

I'm not sure what you are attempting to do here but if there is more than one cookie you're going to need different code in the loop.